# In Python, is it possible to escape newline characters when printing a string?

Tags: python, escaping, newline

I want the newline `\n` to show up explicitly when printing a string retrieved from elsewhere. So if the string is 'abc\ndef' I don't want this to happen:

```
>>> print(line)
abc
def
```

but instead this:

```
>>> print(line)
abc\ndef
```

Is there a way to modify print, or modify the argument, or maybe another function entirely, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Another way that you can stop python using escape characters is to use a raw string like this:

```
>>> print(r"abc\ndef")
abc\ndef
```

or

```
>>> string = "abc\ndef"
>>> print (repr(string))
>>> 'abc\ndef'
```

the only proplem with using `repr()` is that it puts your string in single quotes, it can be handy if you want to use a quote

Answer (score 131):

Just encode it with the `'string_escape'` codec.

```
>>> print "foo\nbar".encode('string_escape')
foo\nbar
```

In python3, `'string_escape'` has become `unicode_escape`.  Additionally, we need to be a little more careful about bytes/unicode so it involves a decoding after the encoding:

```
>>> print("foo\nbar".encode("unicode_escape").decode("utf-8"))
```

[unicode_escape reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

Comment: If the string comes from a DOM object, may need to use 'unicode-escape' instead of 'string_escape'

Comment: The equivalent in Python 3 would be something like `"foo\nbar".encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')`.

Comment: Are the semantics of `.encode('string_escape')` documented anywhere?

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev -- I've added a python3.x compatible answer and a link to the python3 docs.

Answer (score 32):

Simplest method:
`str_object.replace("\n", "\\n")`

The other methods are better if you want to show *all* escape characters, but if all you care about is newlines, just use a direct replace.

Comment: I considered that, but ultimately yeah, I want all escape chars.

Comment: This is not working in 2.7. Use `str_object.replace(r"\n", r"\\n")`.

Comment: No, no, no! There is no difference between Python 2.7 and Python 3. Do as the answer says. `replace(r"\n", r"\\n")` is useless, it will not touch the newlines.

Comment: @WeirdElfB0y You can check whats wrong in your replace by doing `repr(r'\n')` (= `"'\\\\n'"`)   and  `repr('\n')` (= `"'\\n'"`)

Comment: In my case, I needed `str_object.replace("\n", "\\\n")` since the first ``\\`` is a single escaped backslash. But I'm using `python -c ...` for further shell operations.