# Write a file, that writes a file. Problems using newline \n

Tags: python, newline, fwrite

I'm writing on a code to automate `abaqus` scripts, and I want `abaqus` to write the output into a file. Therefore files get written, which run in `abaqus` and include file writing themselves, such as:

```
file = open(filename, "a")

file.write("result_file=open(str('" + str(filename) + "_result'")
```

So far so good, but when I want to use a newline (`"\n"`) in the file that gets written, I obviously get an error:

```
file.write("result_file.write(str(value.data) +'\n')\n")
```

Is there a different way for writing newlines or do I need a different approach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392730/in-python-is-it-possible-to-escape-newline-characters-when-printing-a-string/15393515#15393515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean?

```
file.write("result_file.write(str(value.data) +'\\n')\n")
```

The extra \ escapes the normal function of the .