# string formatting so newline character is visible in Python program

Tags: python, string

I have this list in my Python program:

```py
['-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n', 'MIIEogIBAAKCAQEArLwCLYoy3F29Ror8+k2qWajpz+bSU8oTEe9UiWE0tH2Pq9fY\n', 'JpaSzmFingQe694xr16eK7OiI4b0YfxoQ9MRpYePHbc2yMQO68nU1q8hXRKgtY3I\n', 'HyO+pvS8jgsT9d1qaCaL2jx5SD9WbsgUADVyE+0Y/BKG38R19aca6QDLnpNHEETz\n', 'CogIZEra2X2Qku1DUcCPC+QH1/VfgSrY1nqxkJiqwx7jMcvTR8ygg5KDWCnXwVtM\n', 'k37LqU+4dqpnZ7d3krtzTu2CThIU+kslwFWG6310zOx6nEoHuYjRbbaGs4vi/4P0\n', 'NXwOTCbDyhI9tWIfkFH28OxhJPgOD9yPUcHejQIDAQABAoIBAErt/4/brDZ1n16T\n', 'eivmNuhP4qUh/skEFoOoKyaw+Rj2grVLm2MZ3DMUgaAEL5mnuCvXwos4kDQTHb3H\n', 'rT8Gt1fz1vxP9r7edY6I7f/21mU2aGp5R39ilRh9f7GqUo1L8BWf6vjPVNknSIoj\n', '1rFEfejw5+6o5sL4ySa3x2+dvbZafBNvDMGnfhU8bn4TXtWMhrmP05Xv5W9UdKH2\n', 'VjaOd4MngPadfBG1Q5MG8rMHh+N5uGBQdbg4JbnIAG94thzETlmylTb93UWOZuDr\n', 'KEhJ+UErodUAWT7TO+TdUG9QE8cObM/4efSSrx0SRpIgIY5VFz4OPEgbkzgTef1b\n', 'CF2cSg0CgYEA4RSeCPgtNt73z+szeFvRC7/nh0wStIMVyXM9trZNF2pES6+SXj3N\n', 'ds6fi77PjindivM1MpTWux2i8SVZlLC0HULY7Lv8Ymnkvcl2JKjsAIOT2/QGCzKC\n', 'Aum0euZxMnV4fA32H6iupMIt//ErzPtkwQiQGWI6pqWFDYpvgdZq5+cCgYEAxHaK\n', 'ZOard/XquTdEK5FILS1iXxub8z9REOwfSfkprzThnvulWUJ33JVSF/vJ0fi/3r9I\n', 'gkiEC6pkntYeViDA9WvWLkaf7yKTLpW2p+4WIoW6i+bLBaiBTAM6PBD++RpQx9d0\n', 'i5Lt0I6dYKw9FEmDSOiCsXB5olT1OJ05yAVzZ2sCgYAGiSG5ovM1J65MdEjvUsM0\n', 'MyNW82eLpE7KpbUCDDMa3fQTuopmgCbqLz/EwAqo1yBeu4cs69N8ZXToyavbPHJO\n', 'czV3UlIWzXpd5G6wy9LmhOuTNHfEdXf++6hI9U4OKAkSmRkvfCduE1FgoDEkZ5xa\n', 'WpRMmGSZmC7P4NgyDfbWuwKBgAUd/U7Rf0fZnOqEGP91gkbC9tv5UR+N16O0MsBv\n', 'f/lzTCki7tSbWZniPcgoI8KXUxAPNWlHUEEpiANnGlUt9zitPV/pMQM+iEzfU2me\n', 'Vu9BQnGgaktUb0G2l862tp1wZQg/gWadRhp3jHvXIKQlogjFHZpXjqN+yQBXgAjI\n', 's4/PAoGAaLJkwQjfcJiBsG2x/eQNbubvSNlZpLlfiS+3QRcDQI6MICBMCtQ5pHEQ\n', 'XcjR2Tp1bjnzoUEZWHNiiA/jC7ZZq05OkUnOiHRa9Oj38zsCzlnXKA1bu4wmGbg8\n', 'CtnXrELOu5QRg2eStWqJsQ4kyUioH6UYebFooZa77au/4NNmLgw=\n', '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----']
```

I want to join all items on this list leaving the `\n` newline character visible so that the PEM file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nCtnXrELOu5QRg2eStWqJsQ4kyUioH6UYebFooZa77au/4NNmLgw=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

rather than this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I tried `''.join()` but it left the newline hidden.

Comment: "leaving the \n newline character visible" Do you want the newline character to be *visible* (i.e. it is displayed as ``\n``) or do you want it to be *replaced* (i.e. it is replaced by the two characters ``\`` and ``n``)?

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392971/12797151)? It seems like something you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data_string = repr(''.join(lst))
```

where `lst` is your list.

Comment: Curious to know why this got downvoted. It looks like the simplest of solutions posted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```
string = ''
for i in lst:
    string += i.replace("\n","\\n")

print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an escape character before `\n` to make `\n` as part of string.
Try this before loading the text to file:

```
data = [item.replace("\n", "\\n") for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
Lis=['-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n', 'MIIEogIBAAKCAQEArLwCLYoy3F29Ror8+k2qWajpz+bSU8oTEe9UiWE0tH2Pq9fY\n', 'JpaSzmFingQe694xr16eK7OiI4b0YfxoQ9MRpYePHbc2yMQO68nU1q8hXRKgtY3I\n', 'HyO+pvS8jgsT9d1qaCaL2jx5SD9WbsgUADVyE+0Y/BKG38R19aca6QDLnpNHEETz\n', 'CogIZEra2X2Qku1DUcCPC+QH1/VfgSrY1nqxkJiqwx7jMcvTR8ygg5KDWCnXwVtM\n', 'k37LqU+4dqpnZ7d3krtzTu2CThIU+kslwFWG6310zOx6nEoHuYjRbbaGs4vi/4P0\n', 'NXwOTCbDyhI9tWIfkFH28OxhJPgOD9yPUcHejQIDAQABAoIBAErt/4/brDZ1n16T\n', 'eivmNuhP4qUh/skEFoOoKyaw+Rj2grVLm2MZ3DMUgaAEL5mnuCvXwos4kDQTHb3H\n', 'rT8Gt1fz1vxP9r7edY6I7f/21mU2aGp5R39ilRh9f7GqUo1L8BWf6vjPVNknSIoj\n', '1rFEfejw5+6o5sL4ySa3x2+dvbZafBNvDMGnfhU8bn4TXtWMhrmP05Xv5W9UdKH2\n', 'VjaOd4MngPadfBG1Q5MG8rMHh+N5uGBQdbg4JbnIAG94thzETlmylTb93UWOZuDr\n', 'KEhJ+UErodUAWT7TO+TdUG9QE8cObM/4efSSrx0SRpIgIY5VFz4OPEgbkzgTef1b\n', 'CF2cSg0CgYEA4RSeCPgtNt73z+szeFvRC7/nh0wStIMVyXM9trZNF2pES6+SXj3N\n', 'ds6fi77PjindivM1MpTWux2i8SVZlLC0HULY7Lv8Ymnkvcl2JKjsAIOT2/QGCzKC\n', 'Aum0euZxMnV4fA32H6iupMIt//ErzPtkwQiQGWI6pqWFDYpvgdZq5+cCgYEAxHaK\n', 'ZOard/XquTdEK5FILS1iXxub8z9REOwfSfkprzThnvulWUJ33JVSF/vJ0fi/3r9I\n', 'gkiEC6pkntYeViDA9WvWLkaf7yKTLpW2p+4WIoW6i+bLBaiBTAM6PBD++RpQx9d0\n', 'i5Lt0I6dYKw9FEmDSOiCsXB5olT1OJ05yAVzZ2sCgYAGiSG5ovM1J65MdEjvUsM0\n', 'MyNW82eLpE7KpbUCDDMa3fQTuopmgCbqLz/EwAqo1yBeu4cs69N8ZXToyavbPHJO\n', 'czV3UlIWzXpd5G6wy9LmhOuTNHfEdXf++6hI9U4OKAkSmRkvfCduE1FgoDEkZ5xa\n', 'WpRMmGSZmC7P4NgyDfbWuwKBgAUd/U7Rf0fZnOqEGP91gkbC9tv5UR+N16O0MsBv\n', 'f/lzTCki7tSbWZniPcgoI8KXUxAPNWlHUEEpiANnGlUt9zitPV/pMQM+iEzfU2me\n', 'Vu9BQnGgaktUb0G2l862tp1wZQg/gWadRhp3jHvXIKQlogjFHZpXjqN+yQBXgAjI\n', 's4/PAoGAaLJkwQjfcJiBsG2x/eQNbubvSNlZpLlfiS+3QRcDQI6MICBMCtQ5pHEQ\n', 'XcjR2Tp1bjnzoUEZWHNiiA/jC7ZZq05OkUnOiHRa9Oj38zsCzlnXKA1bu4wmGbg8\n', 'CtnXrELOu5QRg2eStWqJsQ4kyUioH6UYebFooZa77au/4NNmLgw=\n', '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----']
strip_n=x=[i.strip() for i in Lis]
ouput_string= ''.join(strip_n)
```

Hope this helps